# What grammar value of ‘taut’ in the next sentence?

Tags: grammar, verbs, vocabulary

*“Something like that," Oshima said, and stopped, his lips **taut**.*

It’s sentence from ‘Kafka on the shore’ novel.

I think ‘lips’ is subject and ‘taut’ is verb in simple past tense. But I cannot find infinitive of that word. Help me, please!

Comment: Did you look up "taut" in a dictionary?

Comment: (The past tense of "teach" is "taught".)

Comment: @HotLicks, yes. Cambridge Dictionary says it’s adjective. But in this case I expected ‘lips were taut’.

Comment: It's an adjective used in an absolute construction (not to be confused with an 'absolute adjective' meaning 'an adjective with a meaning that is generally not capable of being intensified or compared' [Absolute Adjectives: Definition and Examples - ThoughtCowww.thoughtco.com] or 'an adjective usage not the comparative or superlative usage' {[Internetgrammar](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/adjectiv/compare.htm)}).

Comment: You can think of it as having elided words (and possibly reversed word order), either "his lips [were] taut" or "[with] taut lips".  Such constructions are explained several ways, but the basic point is that they are fairly common in English.

Comment: @HotLicks, thanks for explaining!! I see you. Your answer helped me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Thirsty, we drank."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254228/thirsty-we-drank)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thank you for answer, I understood that ‘lips taut’ is absolute construction.

Comment: Do read the other examples at the duplicate thread.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, much obliged!!!