# Can I use an adjective as a modifier at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: modifiers

For instance,

> Angry, I smashed his head into the wall

Or should it be

> Angrily, I smashed his head into the wall

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Thirsty, we drank."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254228/thirsty-we-drank)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's an excellent answer. My takeaway from it is, "Yes, but in this case don't." Is that what you meant?

Comment: @David K: It's not a matter of ungrammaticality. 'Angry with the concentration camp commander, I smashed his head into the wall' is fine while 'Angry, I smashed his head into the wall' just doesn't work. 'Exhausted, I collapsed into the chair' is also fine, and uses a bare absolute adjective (don't confuse this with the absolute ... comparative ... superlative usage, or with the gradeable v classifying, extreme, absolute classification of adjectives). Devastated and inconsolable would work, but not sad. Size matters here. // Please close-vote as a duplicate if you agree; adverb usage is basic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree, but sadly I'm a few hundred points short of "close vote" privileges here.

Answer (score 10):

It can be either and that depends on what the person  wants to say. If they want to say that  they smashed someone's head into a wall because they were angry, then the first sentence is the right one. if instead they simply want to say  that they were angry while smashing someone's head into a wall, then the second sentence is what has to be used.

Answer (score 6):

The appositive meaning of "*Angry*" and "*he*"  is clear and unambiguous so there is no reason to avoid the construction.

> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/undaunted)
>
> quotes an identical construct, albeit with a participial adjective "*undaunted*":
>
> "*Undaunted, we started to think about the problem.*"

You may also like the example of "*Silent We Stood*", which is the title of a novel by Henry Chappell.

Comment: The variant with the past/passive participle is routine (though beware the dangling thereof); plain adjectives tend to sound a little odder. Also, O.P. has given us not *he* but rather *I* as the main-clause subject for the modifier to modify..

Comment: @BrianDonovan Or if not a little odder, perhaps a little older as though decorated with oratorical flourishes. *Sickly and despairing they came to him; healed and rejoicing they left him.*

Comment: A closer example - in both form and awkwardness - would be `Dauntless, we started to think about the problem.`

Comment: Yes, that is a more precise fit to the prototype. Thanks.