# What do you call this noun phrase that also seems misplaced?

Tags: grammar

"..., the old cockroach brain summoning a hankering for a Papaya dog, or two."

> I did a few valedictory laps, counterclockwise, as always, then began
> chopping my way back uphill, the old cockroach brain summoning a
> hankering for a Papaya dog, or two.

This seems grammatically incorrect. I found it in the New Yorker, and I often see this style in fiction writing. I am curious about what this type of phrase is called. Is it just used for style and rhythm? To me, it feels misplaced. It's referring to the brain of the writer as a young man, but here, it seems like it's referring to "my way back uphill."

Side note: I ask because I'd like to know how to use this structure correctly.

Comment: That's a _nominative absolute._

Comment: Syntactically, the clause is a supplement, more precisely an absolute construction. Note that absolutes require a subject -- here it's "the old cockroach brain". Semantically, the natural interpretation of the supplement is temporal ("while the old cockroach brain ...")

Comment: @BillJ: That was precisely what I thought it was: _a supplement_ with the natural interpretation _while the..._ Feels great to be on the same page as you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Thirsty, we drank."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254228/thirsty-we-drank) (includes the prototypical absolute construction, 'Its hair flowing in the wind, the horse raced along the beach.').

Answer (score 0):

This participle phrase can be seen as elliptical. Here it is without ellipsis:

> climbing my way back uphill, *while* the old cockroach brain *was* summoning a hankering

The subject changes at "the old cockroach brain". Up to that point, it's "I"; then it switches to the brain. The brain is not identified with the young man.

You're right that this is common in fiction, though it's common elsewhere too. Here are some phrases with the same structure:

> The girl patiently built her sand castle on the shore, the waves lapping at her toes.

> My stomach rumbling, I went to the cupboard to find a can of soup.

> We rowed home with a sense of satisfaction with our journey, the loons calling to each other across the lake.

The effect is one of simultaneity, which is useful for creating a vivid setting in narrative, but also just a useful thing to be able to communicate. The ellipsis does elevate the style a little.

Comment: Yes: I would just add that syntactically the non-finite clause is called an 'absolute' construction, one which is subordinate in form but with no syntactic link to the main clause.

Comment: @BillJ Feel free to add where you see fit.