# Is the last word an adjective or the past participle of a verb in "The student looked at him, perplexed."?

Tags: grammar

> The student looked at him, perplexed.

I used a [grammar checker website](https://app.grammarly.com/) to check my sentence. When I substitute 'perplexed' to 'puzzled' (adj), it shows ok, when I substitute it to 'hated' (past tense), it also shows ok.

I have two questions:

1. Can I  use either an adjective or the past participle of a verb to substitute the word 'perplexed'?
2. Is the sentence after the comma called a subordinate clause?

Comment: Grammar checkers are not 100% reliable. _Hated_ would not make sense here. _Perplexed_ or _puzzled_ describe the state of mind of the student, the subject of the sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Thirsty, we drank."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254228/thirsty-we-drank). As with the 'thirsty' example, an adjective classification usually makes most sense, but if a participial adjective has a by-phrase attached ('The student looked at him, perplexed by all that had happened') a verbal classification is preferred by many: a non-dynamic passive.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, "Thirsty, we drank." is a causal relation.It is not a causal in my example, but a depictive construction.

Comment: You're not looking at the answers in the duplicate. 'Its hair flowing in the wind, the horse raced along the beach' shows what is probably best seen as a purely synchronous example. Certainly, 'His hair in glorious disarray, George stood quietly by the shore' does. Like participle clauses, absolutes involve many semantic associations (cause, consequence, precedence, mere synchronicity).

Comment: And here, 'The student looked at him, perplexed' is almost certainly best interpreted by considering that the perplexedness is the reason or part of the reason for the student looking at 'him' (ie not mere synchronicity). // Note that there is **no comma** with subject-orientated (Jim drove the car home drunk) or object-orientated (Jim eats his fish raw) depictive constructions.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for your help. I had read the duplicate, but I didn't understand the relationship between it and my question. First, I did not realize this is a causal relationship(it may be) because there are many times you feel perplexed when you talk with someone or listen to a speech, it doesn't mean you look at someone because you are perplexed. Furthermore, I only focus on if it can use an adjective or past tense, or both. Not just if it is correct to use an adjective.

Comment: With 'The student looked at him, perplexed', it would be infelicitous to require a purely synchronous reading v two sentences would be required, according to Gricean maxims (avoid misleading / ambiguous phrasings).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Ok, thanks!

Comment: The close votes are unwarranted as the linked question does not deal with the principal question - whether 'perplexed' is a past-participle or an adjective in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, only AdjPs work as substitute.

> The student looked at him, happy / enraged / confused.

We know they're adjectives because they can be used predicatively where a past participle would not be allowed with verbs like *seem, look, sound* etc.

> The student seemed happy / enraged / confused.

However, we can't substitute a clear past participial clause like the one below.

> *The student looked at him, **given a fright**.
>
> *The student seemed **given a fright**.
>
> (something) gave the student a fright.

'perplexed' in your example is an adjective phrase functioning as a predicative adjunct according to CaGEL terminology.

It could be expanded:

> The student looked at him, perplexed by the boy's insolence.

Which would still work with *seem, look, sound*, etc.

> He sounded perplexed by the boy's insolance.

The meaning here is pretty similar to the clause:

> The boy's insolence perplexed him.

But since it designates a state that he's in, and behaves otherwise like an AdjP, it's probably best not to analyze it as a clause.

The only way a preterite form (past tense) would be allowed would be in a coordination.

> The student looked at him, went home.
>
> The student looked at him, and went home.

Comment: Doesn't the by-phrase demand 9at least in some cases) a verb interpretation according to CGEL? 'The student sat in silence, badly affected by all that he had recently gone through.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, the presence of a by-phrase is not one of the tests for verbal interpretation as they occur both in AdjPs and past participial clauses. The principal test is whether or not the element in question may occur in a complex-intransitive construction with *seem, became, remain*, etc. There are, of course, cases in which the tests prove inconclusive and either interpretation is allowed. See CaGEL Ch. 16, §10.1.3.

Comment: I'll add 'test _deemed appropriate by CGEL_'. But then I did ask:)

Comment: Thanks DW256. Is the sentence "The student looked at him, given a fright." correct? I'm sorry, I can't understand it's grammar.

Comment: @fitz The sentence "The student looked at him, given a fright." is not grammatical, which is why it is marked with an asterisk.

Comment: @DW256 Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> The student looked at him, perplexed.

In this, perplexed, is a depictive adjective. We can rewrite this as

*The student looked at him [and he was/appeared to be] perplexed.*

You can compare this to

*She arrived at the meeting drunk = She arrived at the meeting [and she was/appeared to be] drunk.*

This differs from

*She arrived at the meeting drunk**ly** (adverb)* = She arrived at the meeting behaving in a manner that indicated she might be drunk.

Your grammar checker accepts "hated" as it is possible, with the appropriate context, for *The student looked at him, hated* to be a coherent sentence.

There is a pdf document [*"Resultative and Depictive Constructions in English"*](https://s-space.snu.ac.kr/bitstream/10371/72455/1/03.pdf) by Chang-Su Lee that gives an overview of these constructions.

Comment: No. This is an absolute construction (whereas the depictive construction 'She arrived / turned up at the meeting drunk' can be telescoped to 'She arrived / turned up drunk', the absolute-containing 'The student looked at him, happy' doesn't reduce to 'The student looked happy': there is a change of meaning).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it is not a question of reducing - it is a question of adding "and he/she, etc.," was".

Comment: 'She arrived at the meeting drunk' and 'She arrived drunk' are examples of the depictive construction. The adjective describes 'her' state obtaining when she arrived. But 'Exhausted, he had to sit down on the bench' describes the reason for his need to sit. There is a causal relation. This compares with the longer absolutes 'His strength failing' or 'Dropping with exhaustion' etc.

Comment: *"But 'Exhausted, he had to sit down on the bench' describes the reason for his need to sit."*  It may well do, given context, but the example does not contain a fronting free-modifier.

Comment: Thanks, I have browsed a part of the pdf document. It helped me a lot, but I didn't find a sentence like "a declarative sentence, verb-ed", you mentioned `Your grammar checker accepts "hated" as it is possible, with the appropriate context, for The student looked at him, hated to be a coherent sentence.` Could you give me an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @fitz It is Germany in 1935: *One of the members of the Hitler Youth stood up and threw a book at Herr Finkelstein, the teacher, and call him a filthy Jew. The book him on the head. The class cheered and more books flew. But Franz did not throw anything. The student looked at Herr Finkelstein, hated, and began to understand what the National Socialists were doing to Germany.*

Comment: @Greybeard You are a hero, many thanks!